# uploading image on web: getting html source code as response

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to upload image on web server, but whenever it tries it is sending me html source code as response and image is not uploaded there. My code is:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteStream);
byte[] buffer = byteStream.toByteArray();

ByteArrayBody body = new ByteArrayBody(buffer,"profile_image");


MultipartEntity entity  = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

entity.addPart("b@gmail.com.jpg", body);

post.setEntity(entity);


System.out.println("post entity length "+entity.getContentLength());
ResponseHandler handler  = new BasicResponseHandler() ;

String response = client.execute(post,handler);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: contact your server side team, what is server is expecting, and he has been used some echo which returns html string instead of proper response.

Comment: yeah may be, will check it out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this Example http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

And change `YourUrl`